# How to convert a string Date in format xx/xx/xxxx or x/x/xxxx into integers of day, month & year using Stoi?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to work out a function that should take a string in format xx/xx/xxxx OR x/x/xxxx and find the day, month 7 year components of the provided string and store them in *day*, *month* & *year* data variables.

I'm looking at using 'std::stoi', which I find straightforward to use for usual numbers, but am having trouble utilizing it for a date.

Comment: Have you heard of [strptime()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel when you can use [`strptime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html)? You'll just have to be careful since the year will be recorded as the number of years since 1900 and the months are 0 indexed:

```
std::string date_string; //Assuming you have your date string here
tm tm_date;
char *ret = strptime(date_string.c_str(), "%d/%m/%Y", &tm_date);

if(!ret) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: Bad input date: " << date_string << std::endl;
    return 1; //or however you handle an error
}

std::cout << "You entered date with Year:" << (tm_date.tm_year + 1900)
     << ", Month:" << (tm_date.tm_mon + 1) 
     << ", Day:" << tm_date.tm_mday << std::endl;
```

See it run here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/7h1Esw)

Comment: It's for a program at Uni that i'm putting together, but we're not allowed to use any time/date headers, so trying to figure out the best way to approach it with stoi.

Comment: @RonanW even without strptime I still wouldn’t use stoi. I’d suggest looking into stringstreams, as they’ll do most of the parsing work for you.